# Annotate part of a method implementation using AspectJ

Tags: aspectj

I have many classes overriding equals for object comparison. For each equals implementation, it uses String .equals which is case sensitive. I'm wondering if it is possible to use AspectJ to simply replace the .equals with .equalsIgnoreCase in each method?

Alternatively, if the above case is not possible, can we use AspectJ to intercept the class to use my own String .equals implementation? (without changing the method implmentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the String.equals(Object anObject) method to be rerouted to equalsIgnoreCase(String) for every occurence of it in your package, correct?

The Pointcut for it will need to intercept calls to equals (`call(boolean equals(Object))`), within your packages (`within(your.packages.*)`) and provide both target (`target(sourceString)`) and parameter (`args(compareString)`), so it should look like this:

```
@Pointcut("call(boolean equals(Object)) && args(compareString) && target(sourceString) && within(your.packages.*)")
protected void equalsPointcut(final Object compareString, final String sourceString) {}
```

The advice using that Pointcut will have to be an around-advice that skips the call to equals and does it's own call to equalsIgnoreCase instead:

```
@Around("equalsPointcut(compareString, sourceString)")
public Object around(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final Object compareString, final String sourceString)
        throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Aspect!");
    return sourceString.equalsIgnoreCase(compareString != null ? compareString.toString() : null);
}
```

The sysout is only there to check that the aspect is actually used and should of course be removed in an actual use case.

My test looks like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String a = "Blaaaa";
    String b = "BLAAAA";

    System.out.println(a.equals(b));
    Object c = new Object();
    System.out.println(c.equals(b));
}
```

And it produces the output:

```
Aspect!
true
false
```

Note that a.equals(b) is rerouted to equalsIgnoreCase (since it's target is a String), but c.equals(b) is not (since it's target is an Object!).

I hope this answers your question. Happy coding! ;)

Comment: It looks like the Aspect is not being invoked. Should I modify anything in my Spring config file? im using cxf

Comment: call is not supported in Spring AspectJ

Comment: Yes, this aspect will not work in Spring AOP. Since you never mentioned Spring, I assumed you were using regular AspectJ. ;) Without the call-Pointcut you will probably be out of luck in this scenario. java.lang.String.equals lies outside your code and can not be adviced by an execution-Pointcut - that is why I used call. So far, I see no way of doing what you want with just Spring AOP.

Comment: Thanks sheltem. To use AspectJ, should I convert the project to AspectJ project in Eclipse? I know for Spring AOP, I should add  `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` and the @Aspect class bean to the spring config file. Not sure how to do for AspectJ.

Comment: Issue resolved. I converted the project to AspectJ and it works. Thanks.

Comment: That... was what I wanted to say next, yes. Depending on how you build your project, just converting it to an AspectJ-project will be enough. Good luck with the rest of your project. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm wondering how this could be applied to String hashCode: I tried to intercept all the calls to hashCode and convert the sourceString to uppercase then return uppercase.hashcode. But I got stackoverflow error. In other words, I would like to change the target (String) to uppercase then invoke .hashCode

Comment: HashCode-methods often call hashCode() for each member of a Class, so your aspect might lead to a huge loop of method calls which then causes the stackoverflow. But it's hard to say without the code and exception. Maybe ask this as a separate question and provide all the necessary information there?